# Manage the reactivity among different visitors

Tags: meteor

As a beginner, I'm building some tests and trainings.
For now, I have a Monkeys collection that displays a list of monkeys names and ages. Visitors can add or remove monkeys. When a visitor adds a monkey to the list, I wish it would not be visible to the others until they update the list with an update button.

I tried several ways without finding how to reach this purpose.
What is the best way? Or what have I to learn to do it?

Here is my js file(and, of course, all is entirely reactive for now).

```js
//Monkeys collection subscription is in the waitOn function in the router.js page
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
Template.hello.helpers({
  monkeys: function(){
     var listMonkeys = Monkeys.find({}, {sort: { age:  -1,  name: 1}});
     return  listMonkeys; 
  }
});
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
 Template.hello.events({
  // insert new monkey
    'submit': function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var name = e.target.new_name.value;
      var age = parseInt(e.target.new_age.value);     
      Monkeys.insert({"name":name,"age":age}, function(error, result) {
        if (error) {alert(error.message);} 
    });
  },
  //delete this monkey
  'click .delete': function(){   
    var name = this.name;
    Monkeys.remove({"_id":this._id}, function(error, result) {
      if (result) {alert(name + " has been deleted");}
      if (error) {alert(error.message);}
    });
  },
  //update listMonkeys
  'click #updatelistMonkeys': function(){
    // ... update function
  }
});
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
//There are only some tests in order to understand how works Meteor startup function
Meteor.startup(function () {
  var listMonkeys = Monkeys.find({}, {sort: { age:  -1,  name: 1}}).fetch();
  console.log("Meteor.startup: ");
console.log(listMonkeys);//return a empty array

Tracker.autorun(function(){
  var listMonkeys = Monkeys.find({}, {sort: { age:  -1,  name: 1}}).fetch();
  console.log("Tracker.autorun: ");
  console.log(listMonkeys)//at first, return a empty array, immediately after,return the filled array
})  
});
```

Here is my html template:

```html
<template name="hello">
<h2>Monkeys forever!</h2>
<button id = "updatelistMonkeys"><img src="images/update-contacts-icon.png"  style= "width: 2em;"></button>
{{#each monkeys}}
 <p class = "listMonkeys">Name: {{name}} - age: {{age}} <button class="delete">X</button></p>
{{/each}}

 <form>
 <legend ><b>Add a new Monkey: </b> </legend>
        <input type="text" name="new_name">
        <input type="number" name="new_age">
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable reactivity within your helper by making two modifications, include the `reactive: false` option and add `.fetch()` to the end, to force the results to be retuned, not a cursor. Try this:

```
monkeys: function() {
    return Monkeys.find({}, {sort: {age: -1, name: 1}, reactive: false}).fetch();
}
```

Got this work around from a github issue:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/771

Comment: I see no need for the fetch() - why not just return the non-reactive cursor?

Comment: According to the defect on github `each` will create its own reactivity and void the setting on the `find` by adding it back to the cursor. If you return an array of results by executing `fetch` it prevents this behavior.

Comment: Of course that issue is 2 years old, so they may have adjusted the behavior since then. It's possible it works without the fetch now.

Comment: It seeems it doesn't work: var listMonkeys = Monkeys.find({}, {sort: {age: -1, name: 1}, reactive: false}).fetch();
     console.log( Monkeys.find({}, {sort: {age: -1, name: 1}, reactive: false}).fetch()); Now, nothing it's displayed. console.log( Monkeys.find({}, {sort: {age: -1, name: 1}, reactive: false}).fetch()); return an empty array

Comment: Since you fetch it, reactive: false isn't necessary - arrays arent reactive

Answer (score 0):

You can load your data from a server method, this solves some problems you have right now but you still need to dev a notification system for your update button to rerun the server method.

```
// server/methods.js
Meteor.methods({
  getMonkeys: function () {
    return Monkeys.find({}, {sort: { age:  -1,  name: 1}}).fetch();
  }
})

//tpl helper
Template.hello.helpers({
  monkeys: function(){
    Meteor.call("getMonkeys", function(err,monkeys){
      if(err){
     //do smth with the error 
     } 
     return monkeys;
   })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

@ Brian Shambien: it still reactive. You can see there ==> monkeys.meteor.com

I suppose it's because the variable is in a reactive context and re-evaluated each time it changes.

```js
Template.hello.helpers({
  monkeys: function(){
    var listMonkeys =  Monkeys.find({}, {sort: {age: -1, name: 1}, reactive: false}).fetch();
    return listMonkeys; 
  }
});
```